# Occupied Bandwidth

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, power-spectral-density, reference-request

I am pretty new in the field of Signal Processing. I am a structural engineering graduate student at the UT at Austin. I am currently working on a project that regards acoustic emission monitoring of a steel-concrete composite bridge.

I am analyzing some Power Density Spectrums that I calculated from the waveforms collected during the experimental program. Now, I am trying to classify some of them basing on Mean Frequency and occupied bandwidth. I have two main questions :

1. Could someone gently suggest some literature reviews where I can read more about this topic?
2. My actual classification method involves the inverse of the occupied bandwidth, so 1/obw. Does it have any meaning  in the field? I mean, is it a feature that could be find anywhere? I also need some literature regarding it.

Comment: The inverse of a frequency is time, and thus, you could interpret the inverse of a bandwidth as "time certainty".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Also, do you think that applying Gabor Uncertainty Principle to have a sort of mathematical prove of the concept could be reasonable ?

Comment: Dear @Marco Manconi: Do you have any clear procedure on how the accoustic excitations were introduced?, Forced? Natural? Are some source receiver testing involved? Of course the badwidth has a clear meaning on this kind of experiments. Why are you forcing introducing a so vague concept (dtdf ratio) in here? The dfdt ratio only is applicable when the sampling time (dt) and the time length (df) are insufficient: meaning you did all the job bad...

Comment: i haven't been too familiar with the term **"occupied bandwidth"**, but i might guess that **Q** (for quality factor).  there are well-known relationships between Q and bandwidth (either in Hz or in octaves) for 2nd-order IIR filters.  that concept can be extended from filter spectrum to signal spectrum.  other than that, i dunno what would be the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

(1) [Here](http://www.calpoly.edu/~cbirdson/Publications/AN011%20Basics%20of%20Structural%20Testing%20%20Analysis.pdf) is one interesting reference on vibration spectral analysis.

(2) Inverse of occupied bandwidth could correspond to a relaxation time of some vibration-- the time it takes the oscillations to die down to a negligible amplitude.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Also, do you think that applying Gabor Uncertainty Principle to have a sort of mathematical prove of the concept could be reasonable ?